# Rotate images from terminal

Tags: command-line, scripts, image-processing, shotwell

I have a directory with a lots of images but they are in the wrong orientation. I want to rotate the images to correct the orientation (mostly ±90<sup>o</sup>). Using image (shotwell photo) viewer I can rotate them individually by clicking the rotate button but that's too tedious.

I looked at `man shotwell` and `shotwell --help-all` but there's nothing that explains how to invoke the rotate command from the command line.

Is there any way I can invoke the rotate command of shotwell (or any other viewer) from the terminal? Or any other methods to rotate images are welcome too.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/432662/15811 if you want it from nautilus. But the terminal command you want is "convert" from "imagemagick"

Comment: If you want a lossless rotation and the files are jpeg, have a look at [jpegtran](http://linux.die.net/man/1/jpegtran); imagemagick will do a [(frankly small) lossy rotation](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=5899).

Comment: and to have jpegtran installed, type: $ sudo apt-get install libjpeg-progs

Answer (score 76, accepted):

If you're looking for a pure bash implementation, ImageMagick's `convert` command is what you're looking for:

```
for szFile in /path/*.png
do 
    convert "$szFile" -rotate 90 /tmp/"$(basename "$szFile")" ; 
done
```

Above will leave existing files intact and copy the newly rotated ones to `/tmp` so you can move or copy them somewhere else or *even replace the existing ones **after the conversion and after verification***.

(and it'll work on all recent releases of Ubuntu as it's standard software)

Comment: This isn't lossless.

Comment: @Geremia That depends on the file format used.  If it's a TIFF or BMP that you rotate and (keep the same destination file format) it will be perfectly lossless.  If you use JPEG or PNG (both lossy file formats) the result will be lossy as well, but that was not what the original question was about...  **0:-)**

Answer (score 50):

```
for file in *.JPG; do convert $file -rotate 90 rotated-$file; done
```

This will copy-**rotate**-and-rename your files.

*If you want to leave the original files untouched just yet, this method may work well for you...*

<sub>Note that this is case-sensitive: if your files are named *.jpg replace with lower-case (or *.png ...) accordingly.</sub>

Answer (score 26):

If you want to overwrite in-place, `mogrify` from the ImageMagick suite seems to be the easiest way to achieve this:

```
# counterclockwise:
mogrify -rotate -90 *.jpg

# clockwise:
mogrify -rotate 90 *.jpg
```

**CAVEAT**: This isn't a lossless rotation method for JPEG files, https://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=5899.
`jpegtran` achieves this (untested):

```
# counterclockwise
ls *.jpg | xargs -n 1 jpegtran -perfect -rotate 270

# clockwise
ls *.jpg | xargs -n 1 jpegtran -perfect -rotate 90
```

Comment: Works perfectly

Comment: Mogrify is quite a Swiss knife when it comes to simple, quick, batch image editing

Comment: best answer, why wouldn't you want to do this in-place?

Comment: @mLstudent33: Good question. It appears that `mogrify` isn't lossless for JPEG files, but `jpegtran` is.

Answer (score 7):

Here's how I do it:

1. Install gThumb

   ```
    sudo apt-get install gthumb
   ```
2. Open up nautilus and go to your images directory. Right click on one and choose `Open with -> gthumb`.
3. Under the `view` menu choose `Browser` or press the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key. This will open the directory browser showing all your images.

   [image]
4. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and select the images you want to rotate or select all of them via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>.
5. On the toolbar, select `Tools` and then `Rotate Right` or `Rotate Left` depending on your preference.

   [image]

Comment: Note that the default jpg output of gthumb has really low quality. Rotations of jpg can be done losslessly with `jpegtran`.

Comment: That doesn't explain how to do it from the terminal.

Answer (score 2):

How about exiftran - transform digital camera jpeg images

I know it's a bit limiting (jpeg) but it has automatic (using exif orientation tag).

```
for photo in *.jpg
  do exiftrans -ia $photo
done
```

About Exiftran,  it is  a command line utility to transform digital camera jpeg images. It can do lossless rotations like jpegtran(1), but unlike jpegtran(1) it cares about the EXIF data: It can rotate images automatically by checking the exif orientation tag; it updates the exif informations if needed (image dimension, orientation); it also rotates the exif thumbnail. It can process multiple images at once

Comment: You can also leave out the `for` loop and simply use: `exiftran -i1 *.JPG`. (I'm using `-1` here to enforce a 180 degree rotation because my files don't have an orientation tag in the EXIF data.) Check `exiftran -h` for more options.

Answer (score 2):

As [krlmlr notes in their answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1078090/1193839), `jpegtran` (installed on Ubuntu with `sudo apt install libjpeg-turbo-progs`) is available for lossless rotation, but because it outputs to standard output, the command to use it would be something like this:

```
$ for img in *.jpg; do jpegtran -rotate 90 -copy all $img > rotated-${img}; done
```

This command will take each file in the current directory, and produce a rotated version (90° clockwise) copy of each file with the new name `rotated-image-name.jpg`. The switch `-copy all` is to copy all metadata to the new file.

For more information see `man jpegtran`.

An additional piece of information given that the original question referenced Shotwell: according to [Shotwell's documentation](http://yorba.org/shotwell/help/edit-nondestructive.html), Shotwell's rotations and other edits will not actually edit the files on disk:

> Shotwell is a non-destructive photo editor. It does not modify your original photographs. That is to say, if you crop a photo or adjust its colors, the photo file on disc remains untouched. Shotwell stores your edits in a database and applies them on the fly as necessary. This means you can undo any alterations you make to a photograph.

Comment: Thanks! Note how counter-clockwise needs 270 as -90 won't be parsed correctly.

Answer (score 1):

A nice solution is to make a set of backups (e.g. prefixed `backup-`), rotate the original files producing a set of new files (prefixed e.g. `rotated-`), giving you a set of

- `img-1.png`
- `backup-img-1.png`
- `rotated-img-1.png`
- `img-2.png`
- *...and so on*

The `mv`/`cp` tools [bash globbing] can only add prefixes, it's messy to take them away (it'd use parameter expansion, ewww...)

The `rename` tool allows you to use `s/before/after/` substitution syntax (from the `sed` tool) to swap that safeguard prefix and overwrite the original files, so your overall process for a given set of pictures `img-`**{1..n}**`.png` would be:

```bsh
for imgf in img-*.png; do mv "$imgf" "backup-$imgf"; done
for imgf in backup-img-*.png; do convert "$imgf" -rotate 90 "rotated-$imgf"; done
```

Note:

- you could use `cp` rather than `mv`, but then there's 2 copies of the original lying around (downside is you get concatenation of prefixes, "`rotated-backup-`...")
- rotation is clockwise (`-rotate 270` gets you 90° anti-clockwise)
- to track progress, add `echo "Rotating ${imgf#backup-} ... ";` after `convert` calls (before `done`)
- for a more compact form (e.g. a set of numbered files), use some parameter expansion like `echo "$(echo ${imgf#backup-img-} | cut -d\. -f 1)...";` instead

  *( You can't remove prefix and suffix in the same bash param expansion hence use `cut` )*

Then after verification you've not messed up, delete the pictures by moving them back to the original

```bsh
rename 's/^rotated-//;' rotated-*
rm backup-img-*
```

Comment: thx for your answer. would you know if this is lossy for jpegs?

Answer (score 1):

You can copy/paste this code, and save it as `rotate.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash -e

CUR_DIR=$(pwd)
cd $1
for file in *.jpg
do
    convert $file -rotate 90 $file
done
cd $CUR_DIR
```

After saving this file, run it from terminal using `./rotate.sh folder_containing_images`.

Comment: Please check your code and the link given!

Comment: This runs serious risk of data loss! You must use quotation marks, thus: `CUR_DIR="$PWD"` (note the simplification of using the built-in variable), `cd "$1"`, `convert "$file" -rotate 90 "$file"` and `cd "$CUR_DIR"`

Comment: You can simplify further by using `pushd` and `popd`. They're great for changing directory and back again.

Answer (score 0):

If you have `ffmpeg` and if your images are numbered consecutively starting from zero with 6 digits, you can rotate them with

```
ffmpeg -pattern_type glob -i '*.jpg' -start_number 0 -vf "transpose=1" -qscale:v 5 %06d.jpg
```

The digit after `qscale:v` controls output quality, lower is better.